# How to get raw XML in WCF Client from Web Service call

Tags: wcf, console-application, wcf-client

I have a WCF Client (console app) that calls a WCF web service and I'm trying to get the raw XML response from within my Console Application.

Does anyone have an idea or code snippet on how to do this?

Comment: Do you actually want the client to process the raw XML, or will WCF tracing to an XML tracelog file suffice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a client Message Inspector

Check out this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2007/08/23/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector.aspx)

In your `BeforeSendRequest` you can simply call ToString() on the message.

Comment: How can doing *anything* BEFORE the request is sent result in showing the RESPONSE...? I'm dying to know.

Comment: @TheDag: He probably opened the link and saw IDispatchMessageInspector.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get the raw xml using this method:

```
string _serial = SerializeObj(retVal);

public string SerializeObj<T>(T obj)
        {
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());

            using (StringWriter txtWriter= new StringWriter())
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(txtWriter, obj);
                return txtWriter.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: This returns the value after it has already been processed by WCF.  It does not return the *raw* xml